# How to open a Kendo ui window from another window?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I could successfully open a Kendo Window by clicking on the menu.

My requirement is like, if I click on a button on this window, it should dynamically create an iframe and append to a div and append this new div to the parent container and show as a new window just like I open it from the menu.

I could successfully add the iframe and div to the parent, but when I open the window, its open inside the the window where I am and not from the parent container. My code is as below:

```
  $("#btn").click(function () {

        var k = "<div id='kk'><iframe style='height:600px;width:900px'></div>";
        $("#menuDiv", parent.document).append(k);

        $("#kk", parent.document).kendoWindow();
    });
```

Comment: A window inside a window? What is your final goal? Maybe there is a simpler approach.

Comment: Hi Onabai, my menu contains a submenu which has 100 different items in it. If I display that inside the menu, it will look ugly. My goal is like to separate these menu items and show all the menu names inside a grid and when I click one item it shows up as if I clicked one of the menu item

Comment: but that doesn't require having one window inside the other or having it with iframe. If it is only a window opened from another please let me know and I think that I can help

Comment: I sorted it by using a kendo grid inside the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that windows are floating despite of the HTML element that contains it, opening it from another one or even dynamically generating the content of the opened window is pretty simple.

Given the following HTML code that contains the original window:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="win1">
        <h1>Window 1</h1>
        <button id="open" class="k-button">Open</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

We define a `click` handler for the button as:

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
    var w2 = $("<div>Window2</div>");
    $("#container").append(w2);
    w2.kendoWindow({});
});
```

Where we append the second window (`w2`) dynamically generated to the `container` of the first window and then we initialize it as a `kendoWindow`.

We might have added the second window to the first one as doing:

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
    var w2 = $("<div>Window2</div>");
    w1.element.append(w2);
    w2.kendoWindow({});
});
```

Where `w1` is `var w1 = $("#menuDiv").data("kendoWindow");` but that doesn't make any difference since windows are floating elements not constrained to it's parent HTML node.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/juunjch1/

And if you want that the content of the opened window is an `iframe` you should actually create the `window` with the option `iframe` set to `true`. Something like:

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
    var w2 = $("<div>Window2</div>");
    $("#container").append(w2);
    w2.kendoWindow({
        content: "http://www.telerik.com",
        iframe: true
    });
});
```

And you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/juunjch1/2/